# an irreducible affine curve is normal if and only if it is nonsingular

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

> An  is normal if and only if it is nonsingular.

This statement comes from Kemper, *A Course in Commutative Algebra*. He says to use Proposition 8.10 and Theorem 14.1.

[image]

**Theorem 14.1.** *A Noetherian local ring of dimension one is regular if and only if it is normal.*

An irreducible affine curve is normal means that the coordinate ring $K[X]$ is normal. So, by the Proposition, for every $x$, the localization $K[X]_x$ is normal. 
How can I get that $K[X]_x$ is regular?  Is that $K[X]_x$ is a local ring? Could someone tell me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algebraic variety $X$ is regular if all of its local rings $O_{X,x}$ are regular local rings. The latter means that the maximal ideal $M_{X,x}$ of $O_{X,x}$ is generated by $\mathrm{dim}(O_{X,x})$ elements.

Since regularity of a ring is stable under localization it suffices to require that the local rings $O_{X,x}$ in closed points of $X$ are regular.

Regular local rings are normal - in fact they are factorial by a famous theorem due to Auslander and Buchsbaum.

Now for a curve $X$ the dimension of every local ring $O_{X,x}$ in a closed point equals $1$. Hence if $x$ is regular $M_{X,x}$ must have one generator. Theorem 14.1 in combination with the mentioned normality yields the result.

Comment: What's the local ring of an affine variety ?

Comment: If $X$ is an algebraic variety over a (algebraically closed) field $K$. Then the (closed) points of $X$ correspond to the prime (maximal) ideals of the coordinate ring. The local ring $O_{X,x}$ is the localization $K[X]_p$ of the coordinate ring at the prime ideal $p$ corresponding to the point $x$.